# Q: Is there exist the statement P which is satisfying following conditions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

```
Let P be a statement. Let f be a function.
```

> $\exists$ $P$ $\exists$ $f$ : $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$ 
>   $\exists$ $a$, $b$ ($\ne$ $a$) $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that (i) , (ii)
>   and (iii) are all equivalent statements.
>
> (i) $P$
>
> (ii) $\forall$ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ , $f(n) > a$
>
> (iii) $\forall$ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ , $f(n) > b$

1) I want to have information related to this problem.
Is it possible to *prove* or *disprove*?

2) If  the statement $P$ exists, what does this mean?

I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here might be a simpler way to think this:

Let $f(x)=\max(a,b)+1$, that is a constant function

Then ii) and iii) must be True in this condition, which is a tautology

Have ii)$\Leftrightarrow\top$ and iii)$\Leftrightarrow\top$

Therefore we let $P$ be any tautology would work

for example define $P$ iff $\top$ or define $P$ iff $1=1$ etc.

Hence it's true

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a nice day : )